# How to implement a lazy constant-space tri-partition function?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghc

I have generalized the existing `Data.List.partition` implementation

```
partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
partition p xs = foldr (select p) ([],[]) xs
  where
    -- select :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> ([a], [a]) -> ([a], [a])
    select p x ~(ts,fs) | p x       = (x:ts,fs)
                        | otherwise = (ts, x:fs)
```

to a "tri-partition" function

```
ordPartition :: (a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> ([a],[a],[a])
ordPartition cmp xs = foldr select ([],[],[]) xs
  where
    -- select :: a -> ([a], [a], [a]) -> ([a], [a], [a])
    select x ~(lts,eqs,gts) = case cmp x of
        LT -> (x:lts,eqs,gts)
        EQ -> (lts,x:eqs,gts)
        GT -> (lts,eqs,x:gts)
```

But now I'm facing a confusing behaviour when compiling with `ghc -O1`, the 'foo' and 'bar' functions work in constant-space, but the `doo` function leads to a space-leak.

```
foo xs = xs1
  where
    (xs1,_,_) = ordPartition (flip compare 0) xs

bar xs = xs2
  where
    (_,xs2,_) = ordPartition (flip compare 0) xs

-- pass-thru "least" non-empty partition
doo xs | null xs1  = if null xs2 then xs3 else xs2
       | otherwise = xs1
  where
    (xs1,xs2,xs3) = ordPartition (flip compare 0) xs


main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ foo [0..100000000::Integer] -- results in []
    print $ bar [0..100000000::Integer] -- results in [0]
    print $ doo [0..100000000::Integer] -- results in [0] with space-leak
```

So my question now is,

1. What is the reason for the space-leak in `doo`, which seems suprising to me, since `foo` and `bar` don't exhibit such a space leak? and
2. Is there a way to implement `ordPartition` in such a way, that when used in the context of functions such as `doo` it performs with constant space complexity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a space leak. To find out whether a component list is empty, the entire input list has to be traversed and the other component lists constructed (as thunks) if it is. In the `doo` case, `xs1` is empty, so the entire thing has to be built before deciding what to output.

That is a fundamental property of all partitioning algorithms, if one of the results is empty, and you check for its emptiness as a condition, that check cannot be completed before the entire list has been traversed.

Comment: Thanks, but I've got a bonus question then which still confuses me: If I have a `baz` function with the definition `baz xs = (xs1,xs2) where (xs1,xs2,_xs3) = ordPartition (flip compare 0) xs`, why does that need to hold on to the value of `_xs3` (when `foo` and `bar` didn't need to?)

Comment: It doesn't. Since the result depends in no way on `_xs3`, that can be forgotten. It may happen that the selector thunk optimisation doesn't fire and there's a reference to `_xs3` through the tuple kept alive, but that's an accident. The thing in `doo` is that `xs1` is needed to find out what the result is. Until that question is answered, nothing can be dropped because it might be needed. And if, as in the example, that question cannot be answered before everything has been processed, everything potentially needed for the result must be kept.

Comment: It seems in fact to be a non-fired optimization (in the case of `baz`); if I change the `(,)` constructor to a `(++)` application, or if I add bang-patterns to `xs1` and `xs2` the thunks I'm seeing are avoided... Is this worth being reported as a ghc bug-report?

Comment: Better too many reports than unreported bugs. But there are already some tickets concerning that, so you may search and see if it's better to respond to an existing ticket. However, if it's a regression, do open a new ticket.

Comment: @is7s `-O2` makes no difference here; I guess part of the reason is that `(a,b)` is still made up of two lazy values `a` and `b`, of which it's not clear which will be actually needed later on...

Comment: @hvr Is your `baz` small enough to share that we can see what's going on?

Comment: @DanielFischer I provided the definition of the `baz` function in my first comment, or do you need/want something else?

Comment: My bad, I thought we'd need some surrounding code. I just tried it out and: **It's a regression**, 6.12.3 uses constant memory. Looking at the core to see if I understand what went wrong.